# clicking on a button in selenium webdriver blocks next click

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
driver.findElement(By.id("readText")).click();
System.out.println("reading text");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("readText")).click();
```

This snippet executes till printing 'reading text' but does not call the further code. The readText button is visible. But next steps are not executed.
Firefox version: 44.0.2
Selenium WebDriver version: 2.48.2

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Best method to wait is waitforelementtobevisible, i would suggest don't use Explicit wait.

Comment: There is no error, the readText button is clicked the first time. After that none of the statements are executed. The readText button plays text continuously

Comment: try once without thread.sleep, if required use implicity wait